# IllustratorCS6 - Rounded rectangle stroke is not rounded also

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I have a shape created with the rounded rectangle tool and when I add a stroke to it, the inside corners of the stroke are not rounded. Is there a way to make them rounded without creating 2 separate objects?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're looking at.

Comment: I've added the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inside corners *are* rounded, they are merely proportionally rounded based upon the weight of the stroke. The thicker the stroke, the less rounded the inside corners become.

If you absolutely want inner rounding to match the outer rounding there are a couple options.....

Move your stroke *under* the [Fill] item in the **Appearance Panel**.

After doing so you may need to increase the weight of the stroke, since half of it will be hidden by the fill.

[image]

Or change the stroke alignment to the *outside* on the **Stroke Panel**.

[image]

Comment: You're right! when I zoom way in on a corner, the inside IS rounded, just way too tight of a radius. Aligning the stroke to the outside probably would've been the simplest solution, but I already went with 2 separate objects using the rounded rect. tool.  I found a great tip that while you are dragging out your rounded rect, before you let go of the mouse button, you can use the up and down arrow buttons to adjust the radius.

Comment: Try holding down the ~ (tilde) key while dragging @ChrisM :)

Comment: interesting.  not sure when I would ever use that, but interesting to say the least. ty